# launch Blackberry app from link in mail

Tags: blackberry

I can not be more clear with the title :D

Is it possible? to launch an application on a blackbeery just cliking on a "link" inside a mail? i read about taping a url and going to the application but this is much more specific.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can listen incoming emails. 
You can implement menu item that will be available in mail app.
But you can also implement content handler with specific URI to launch your app.

All examples are available in BB samples.

Comment: i have to make it work with 5.0 and examples are not posible for this, at least eclipse doesnt let me import them. On 7.0 i can see some examples, can u provide me the name of the ones i should check?? i was looking at httpfiltrerdemo

Comment: Here is for content provider [example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Create_BB_app_plays_media_from_a_user_734821_11.jsp)

Comment: @GuillermoVarini Hi, did u get any solution for this problem. I am also facing the same problem. Can u help me??

Answer (score 0):

Look in the RIM sample apps, more specifically HTTPFilterDemo.

You have to register a filter for the type of link you need the app to be triggered by (you'll need to put this code in the main method of you app):

```
HttpFilterRegistry.registerFilter("www.rim.com","com.rim.samples.device.httpfilterdemo.filter");
```

where "www.rim.com" is obviously the link that should open the app and the second parameter is the package that contains the "Protocol" class. The Protocol class has a callback method:

```
public Connection openFilter( String name, int mode, boolean timeouts ) throws IOException {
```

This method will be called each time the user clicks on a link that has the form specified by you. So, to open the app, in the "openFilter" method, do:

```
int modHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("YourAppModuleName");
        ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(modHandle);
        try {
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(apDes[0]);
        } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```